# Centered div block fixed but doesn't work on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div blocks:

- 1st: left-aligned
- 2nd: center-aligned
- 3rd: right-aligned

The 2nd block (centered) is fixed so whenever user scroll this one is still in the center of the page.

The problem: doesn't work on Google Chrome.

```css
#generic-container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#generic-left {
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 270px);
    /*background: #ff0000;*/
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#generic-center {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    width:450px;
    height: 360px;
    /*background: #00ff00;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -180px;
}

#generic-right {
    float:right;
    width: calc(50% - 260px);
    /*background: #0000ff;*/
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="generic-container">
    <div id="generic-left">
        aa aa aa aa aa aa 
    </div>
    <div id="generic-center">
        <div>
            bb bb bb bb bb
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="generic-right">
        cc cc cc cc cc
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to horizontal alignment?

Comment: Yes I am referring to horizontal alignment.

Comment: It looks like you have an unnecessary `<div>`  below `<div id="generic-center">`

Comment: Removing this `unnecessary` div doesn't change anything to the problem.

Comment: You just need a left: calc(50% - 225px); or left: 50%; margin-left: -225px; on the center item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**CSS**

```
#generic-container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#generic-left {
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 225px);
    /*background: #ff0000;*/
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#generic-center {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    width:450px;
    height: 360px;
    /*background: #00ff00;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -180px; // Beware this rule is confusing
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: -225px;
    left: 50%;
}

#generic-right {
    float:right;
    width: calc(50% - 225px);
    /*background: #0000ff;*/
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/c0ur8buc/)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for :

Just removed the "text-align" in #generic-container and "div" inside "generic-center"

**Css :**

```
 #generic-container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    border: solid 2px yellow;
}

    #generic-left {
        float:left;
        width: calc(50% - 270px);
        /*background: #ff0000;*/
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: solid 2px red;
    }

#generic-center {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    width:450px;
    height: 360px;
    text-align:center;
    /*background: #00ff00;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -180px;
    border: solid 2px green;
}

#generic-right {
    float:right;
    width: calc(50% - 260px);
    /*background: #0000ff;*/
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: solid 2px blue;
}
```

**Html :**

```
<div id="generic-container">
    <div id="generic-left">
        aa aa aa aa aa aa 
    </div>
    <div id="generic-center">
        bb bb bb bb bb
    </div>
    <div id="generic-right">
        cc cc cc cc cc
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/Dilraj7/pen/ZYgNZJ

Comment: Wrong link forgive me! I updated the link (tell me if its working because im also using chrome its working for me). Anyhow i think you find the solution given up :) Good luck in your work